# How to synthetically add activity to back stack before starting another one?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, kotlin, back-stack

Let's say I'm in activity A. I want to start activity B, but I want the user to be taken to activity C if they press back on activity B.

So even though the user sees A -> B, I want it to be A -> C -> B.

I know I could use `TaskStackBuilder` and synthetically create the ABC stack. However, sometimes A isn't simply one activity; there might be some previous navigation the user did that I don't want to lose and that would be too much trouble to synthetically recreate with `TaskStackBuilder`.

Is there a way to use `TaskStackBuilder` keeping the current back stack? Or is there any other way to synthetically add an activity to the back stack before starting another one?

Answer (score 1):

What you may do is override `onBackPressed()` in Activity `B`, from where you will launch activity `C` and finish activity `B`. From user's perspective he will see:

A -> B -> (back press event) -> C

In backstack:

A -> AB -> AC

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```